# Recorrer los objetos duplicados de un array y sumar la cantidad

Tags: array, json, objeto, foreach

tengo un problema. No logro sumar una propiedad de los objetos al encontrar coincidencias. Intenté muchas formas.

Tengo un input en la cual si su valor.lenght es = a 6 entonces que busque en un objeto si existe, y si existe que agregue ese valor a un array en forma de objeto.

La idea es que todos esos objetos encontrados si estan duplicados que los meta en otro array pero sumando la cantidad de repetidos.

cabe destacar que el JSON es obtenido a través de un excel.

```js
var result = {"Hoja1":[{"Código":"LB3095","Descripción":"Helad NF SAMSUNG RT32K5070S8 320L Sil","Marca":"CETROGAR","Familia":"Linea Blanca","Categoría":"Linea Blanca","stock":0,"ec":-1,"total":-1},{"Código":"LB3057","Descripción":"Microond Atma 23 Lts Digital MD1823 Silv","Marca":"CETROGAR","Familia":"Linea Blanca","Categoría":"Linea Blanca","stock":0,"ec":0,"total":0},{"Código":"LB3063","Descripción":"Lavarr Drean Next 10.12 P eco 1200rpm","Marca":"CETROGAR","Familia":"Linea Blanca","Categoría":"Linea Blanca","stock":0,"ec":0,"total":0},{"Código":"LB3114","Descripción":"Cocina Longvie 13501XF inox rej f +timer","Marca":"CETROGAR","Familia":"Linea Blanca","Categoría":"Linea Blanca","stock":0,"ec":0,"total":0},{"Código":"LB3115","Descripción":"Cocina Longvie 21501X acero display touc","Marca":"CETROGAR","Familia":"Linea Blanca","Categoría":"Linea Blanca","stock":0,"ec":0,"total":0},{"Código":"LB3120","Descripción":"Lavasecarr Longvie LS-18012 8Kg 1200rpm","Marca":"CETROGAR","Familia":"Linea Blanca","Categoría":"Linea Blanca","stock":0,"ec":0,"total":0},{"Código":"LB3138","Descripción":"Cocina Whirlpool WF560XTDNB Inox 4h e/elec 60cm","Marca":"CETROGAR","Familia":"Linea Blanca","Categoría":"Linea Blanca","stock":0,"ec":0,"total":0},{"Código":"LB3139","Descripción":"Cocina Whirlpool WF360XGDNB Inox 4h e/el","Marca":"CETROGAR","Familia":"Linea Blanca","Categoría":"Linea Blanca","stock":0,"ec":0,"total":0},{"Código":"LB3156","Descripción":"Horno Morelli SAHO H6 Inox. pta ciega GE","Marca":"CETROGAR","Familia":"Linea Blanca","Categoría":"Linea Blanca","stock":0,"ec":0,"total":0},{"Código":"LB3158","Descripción":"Cocina Philco electr PHCH050B 50cm","Marca":"CETROGAR","Familia":"Linea Blanca","Categoría":"Linea Blanca","stock":0,"ec":0,"total":0},{"Código":"LB3189","Descripción":"Helad HAUSER 322L HM160 BL HCA1 c/f","Marca":"CETROGAR","Familia":"Linea Blanca","Categoría":"Linea Blanca","stock":0,"ec":0,"total":0},{"Código":"LB3190","Descripción":"Helad HAUSER 322L HM162 GP HCA1 PL c/f","Marca":"CETROGAR","Familia":"Linea Blanca","Categoría":"Linea Blanca","stock":0,"ec":0,"total":0},{"Código":"LB3191","Descripción":"Helad NF SAMSUNG RT29K577JS8 299L c/disp","Marca":"CETROGAR","Familia":"Linea Blanca","Categoría":"Linea Blanca","stock":0,"ec":0,"total":0},{"Código":"LB3177","Descripción":"Helad Patrick 264Ls HPK-135B01 C/F","Marca":"CETROGAR","Familia":"Linea Blanca","Categoría":"Linea Blanca","stock":0,"ec":0,"total":0},{"Código":"LB3195","Descripción":"Lavarr Whirlpool WNQ07AB 7KG 1000RPM","Marca":"CETROGAR","Familia":"Linea Blanca","Categoría":"Linea Blanca","stock":0,"ec":0,"total":0},{"Código":"LB3204","Descripción":"Cocina Florencia electr 8637F Ne 56cm","Marca":"CETROGAR","Familia":"Linea Blanca","Categoría":"Linea Blanca","stock":0,"ec":0,"total":0},{"Código":"LB3233","Descripción":"Microond BGH QChef 23L B223DS20 800w Gri","Marca":"CETROGAR","Familia":"Linea Blanca","Categoría":"Linea Blanca","stock":0,"ec":0,"total":0},{"Código":"LB3240","Descripción":"Helad NF Whirlpool 462L WRM56K2 Inox INV","Marca":"CETROGAR","Familia":"Linea Blanca","Categoría":"Linea Blanca","stock":0,"ec":0,"total":0},{"Código":"LB3265","Descripción":"Freez Inelro 280L Refri R600 FIH350A+","Marca":"CETROGAR","Familia":"Linea Blanca","Categoría":"Linea Blanca","stock":0,"ec":0,"total":0},{"Código":"LB3291","Descripción":"Lavarr Gafa fuzzy Fit 7kg 750rpm Bl","Marca":"CETROGAR","Familia":"Linea Blanca","Categoría":"Linea Blanca","stock":0,"ec":0,"total":0},{"Código":"LB3295","Descripción":"Lavarr Philco 8kg 1200rpm PHLF081B CF","Marca":"CETROGAR","Familia":"Linea Blanca","Categoría":"Linea Blanca","stock":0,"ec":0,"total":0},{"Código":"LB3430","Descripción":"Freez Inelro 280L Refri R600 FIH350A++INV","Marca":"CETROGAR","Familia":"Linea Blanca","Categoría":"Linea Blanca","stock":0,"ec":0,"total":0},{"Código":"LB3451","Descripción":"Cocina Gafa 56 cm CGB56 Bl","Marca":"CETROGAR","Familia":"Linea Blanca","Categoría":"Linea Blanca","stock":0,"ec":0,"total":0};//almacenamos el JSON con el stock completo

var inp = document.getElementById('search');//seleccionamos el input

var searching = [];//almacenamos los valores del input que se encontraron en el stock completo ej {cod:LB3095, cant:1},{cod:LB3095, cant:1},{cod:LB3195, cant:1},

var duplicados = [];
inp.addEventListener("input", () => {
    
    var inpValor = inp.value.toUpperCase();

    var tableInp = document.getElementById('tableInp');

    if (inpValor.length == 6) {

        result.Hoja1.forEach(j => {
            if (j.Código == inpValor) {
                searching.push({ cod: inpValor, cant: 1 });
                //AQUI TENDRIA QUE BUSCAR Y ENCONTRAR REPETIDOS PARA COLOCARLOS EN OTRO ARRAY
            }
        });

    }

});
```

Comment: comparte tu JSON así podemos replicar tu código y probarlo

Comment: listo. lo cargué en la variable result. linea1

Comment: ¿Puedes ser más claro y dejar un ejemplo de entrada y resultado esperado?

Comment: suponiendo que hago varias busquedas la cual las va almacenando en la variable searching, ejemplo: var searching = [{cod: LB3095, cant: 1}, {cod: LB3191, cant: 1}, {cod: LB3095, cant: 1}]; 

al tener esa variable. necesito alguna función que a medida que vaya agregando mas objetos con el input, se vayan agrupando en otra variable este resultado. ejemplo: var repetidosEncontrados = [{cod: LB3095, cant: 2}, {cod: LB3195, cant: 1}];

la idea seria que una función vaya encontrando los repetidos e ir sumando su cantidad encontrada.